# Hide server location

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, security

I have a few resources running on machines on my local network that I thought would be nice to share with some of my online friends. The problem is that I would prefer they not know where I live. Is there any reliable way that I can obscure the location of my server? Currently it runs Ubuntu 14.04 and a service that accepts connections on a single port (as far as I'm aware, it doesn't use any other ports in the process).  I'm willing to invest money into this (rent a vps/proxy/whatever), so long as I can be fairly sure that my home IP is not exposed.  I can't host it remotely as the service relies on hardware that would be extremely costly for me to rent (especially when I already own it).

Comment: Using a VPS instead of a machine on your local network will definitely prevent anyone from accessing your location based on IP.

Comment: An IP address cannot identify an address you don't have to do anything. At best it'll tell people what *city* you probably live in.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq I know it won't lead directly to my house, but I don't really want any knowledge of my location shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually quite easy to do, provided you **do** have a Linux machine that will substitute for your true address.

All you have to do is to redirect traffic arriving on this new machine to your home machine via the following `iptables` command:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1111 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2:1111
```

Also, you will need

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

otherwise your home computer will reply directly to your friends, thus betraying your true home address. And you need to enable IPv4 forwarding,

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Now you can communicate to your friends your VPS IP address, instead of your home's.

If you rent a cheap VPS server to do this (I have one with unlimited traffic for three dollars per month), make sure the amount of traffic included in your subscription is large enough to accommodate your projected needs.

Comment: Will this prevent me from sshing into the server that will be doing the forwarding?  I don't have physical access or any other means of remote controlling the system I plan on using.  It looks to me like this only operates on port 1111, but better safe than sorry.  Also, the second iptables command you give should be run on my server at home, correct?

Comment: @haze No, all of the commands above are to be run on the remote pc, **not** at home. Also, no , this will **not** prevent you from ssh'ing into the remote server.  Just use it as it is written, to redirect only the port you are interested in (TCP1111 in the fictitious example above).

Comment: When I was testing this solution, I found that unfortunately I could get the service's ip by using traceroute.  Any way to prevent things like this?

Comment: @haze Use iptables to block pings: `iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP`

Answer (score 2):

There's heaps of ways to do this, with varying levels of security, speed, reliability, and cost.

Here's just a few I can think of:

- Configure a Tor hidden service on your machine.  Your friends access the service via the .onion link.  Your friends will need to have and know how to use Tor for this to work.
- Rent a VPS.  Amazon will let you have a simple EC2 instance for free for a year.  Use this to reverse proxy traffic to your server.  There are a lot of ways to do this, too, including one very simple ssh command: `ssh you@yourserver -R <remotePort>:localhost:<servicePort>`.
- Host the service on a VPS instead of at home.